# The use of taking (an) interest

Tags: ambiguity, collocation, zero-article

Is the following question correct?

> What's wrong with **taking interest**?

I know *taking AN interest* or *showing interest* is better, but I would like to know if *taking interest* is also correct.

Comment: I can't comment on the grammar, but *taking interest* sounds a little bit like *charging interest*. At least, that's what occurred to me.

Comment: The context determines whether to use an article (sometimes indifinite article and sometime definite article) in such constructions. The meaning is different in each case. Note that in the sentence, *interest* without any article uses the word in a broader, generic sense. This is a more generic question that keeps coming up on this site and maybe [ell.se] as well from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with "[taking interest](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/interest)". Interest can be used as a singular countable noun or as a mass noun with the same meaning:

> - ***[ S or U ]*** the feeling of wanting to give your attention to something or of wanting to be involved with and to discover more about something:
>
>   - ***I've always had an interest in astronomy.*** He never seems to show any interest in his children. 
>       **Unfortunately, I lost interest half way through the film.** 
>       She takes more of an interest in politics these days.
>       informal Just out of interest, how old is your wife?

Cambridge Dictionary

From [E-English Grammar](https://books.google.it/books?id=NSlkBgAAQBAJ&pg=PP6&dq=%22taking%20interest%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHup_6tvXPAhXDLhoKHQhJBnsQ6AEIHzAB#v=onepage&q=%22taking%20interest%22&f=false):

> - Gradually the children ***start taking interest in drawing*** and in course of drawing can learn a lot of things and can fair in their classes as soon as they are admitted to school in the nursery classes. When it is confirmed that the ***children are taking interest in learning***, the parents should be more attentive than it is proper to teach  ...

Comment: This is just wrong. *Interest* as a noun can be countable or uncountable, but you can't use them interchangeably.  You can only *take* or *have **an** interest* in something (and, conversely, you can only *lose **[]** interest* in something). This is perhaps an idiomatic usage, without much logical justification, but that's the way it is. (That second source is not remotely reliable. In addition to needing an *an* before *interest*, the first sentence is missing a *the* before *course* and goes completely off the rails with *can **fair** in their classes*.)

Comment: @1006a - 1) though I agree that "take an interest in" something is a more common construction, I'd not say that "take interest in"  something is uncommon or wrong. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+interest+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctake%20interest%20in%3B%2Cc0 -2) why do you say that the source I cite is totally unreliable?

Comment: Hmm, you may be correct that it is a more common usage than I had thought. However, I strongly suggest that you find a different authority than the second citation. I say that it is unreliable as an exemplar of English usage because every sentence of it I have looked at contains rudimentary errors like ***They** children should be taught **as to how** draw lines differently* or complete gibberish like ***the parents should be more attentive than it is proper to teach them how to write letters and figures***.